# RabbitMQ internal monitoring and alerting system

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am new to RabbitMQ and was checking if there is an inbuilt alerting system with plugins.

RabbitMQ is installed on a server (aws ec2) and many docker containers (containers on aws ecs) are listening to it. This was working fine but suddenly it hangs and none of the queue had consumers.

Is it possible to have monitoring system setup such as to send an email alert when there is no consumers in queue or when the RabbitMQ fails.

there is an inbuild command

> rabbitmq-diagnostics -q ping

but not sure how it can be used to monitor the server continuously and send alert. Should we use some external tools like nagios?

Answer (score 2):

Rabbitmq has couple of plugins which can send metrics to AWS cloudwatch, grafana and other monitoring tools.

This [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html) gives you more details about the list of monitoring plugins available for rabbitmq.

This [link](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-cloudwatch-exporter/blob/master/README.md) gives more detail about how you can send custom metrics to cloudwatch from rabbitmq.

Once you push all the rabbitmq metrics to AWS cloudwatch, then you can configure alarms based on your requirements and thresholds.